# Stop Android Studio from using Support Library

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I'm trying to get my Android project in Android Studio to NOT use the Support library. My issue is that when I use fragments it is expecting support fragments and causing the app to crash.

My Min SDK is 14 and my Target SDK is 19. My understanding is that because I'm targeting these versions I should not need the support library. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm trying to correct this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. And I am aware I can fix it by just using `SupportMapFragment` instead. But I do not want to do this. I want to use the regular MapFragment

So my main question is how can I get it to stop expecting support library fragments and just use regular fragments. I've also had this issue with other fragments not just the map.

Comment: There are some features that support v4 Fragments support that are not supported in v14 devices such as nested fragments (added in v16). Do you have a reason why specifically you would not want to use v4 Fragments (particularly since you might want other classes from the support library like `ViewPager`)?

Comment: I thought there may be some incompatibilities down the road. I figure support libraries take longer to get the latest features. But after looking into this a bit more I may be wrong. I think for this project I may leave it as v4. But I am still curious how to stop a project from using this. If all I need to do is create a project with a higher min sdk version please create an answer stating so and I will mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Google updates the support library alongside the platform version (i.e., the latest revision 19 came out at the same time as API level 19) so incompatibilities wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've removed the support library from the `build.gradle`, and there's no file in the `libs` folder, have you made sure to delete the imports?

From the error message, it looks like you'll have the following import (else the error wouldn't know about trying to cast to a support Fragments) at the top of your class:

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Delete this, replace it with:

`import android.app.Fragment;`

Do this with all the support references.

Comment: You are correct. I did end up finding imports in the project elsewhere that I was not aware of when I posted this. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, good to hear you got it sorted. As others have said though, the compatibility library is updated at the same time as the platform - if you want the latest features and still be able to access the majority of the Android user base, you _have_ to use the compat library.

Answer (score 13):

I'm surprised no one can still give you a straight forward answer. I hope my response will help.

So to stop Android Studio from using support library especially the infamous AppCompat v7, follow these few steps:

1) Gradle Scripts > build.gradle(Module: app)

2) Remove the line that says `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'`

3) res/values/styles.xml > change the parent value to: `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`

4) AndroidManifest.xml > change the application android:theme to: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`

5) Go into your activities and remove the line that imports the support library. Change it to: `import android.app.Activity;`

6) Now in the menu bar: Build > ReBuild Project. Correct any errors then keep rebuilding until you get it to work, then run your project to ensure nothing crashes and your references are in order.

For me I got errors stating that I app:ShowAsAction is not supported or so. I had to change it to android:ShowAsAction. Just Make sure that for any error, you read it carefully and follow the suggestions in the little dialogues boxes that pop up beside the error line.

Answer (score 1):

To completly remove the suppport library, go to the package explorer window, and in

your project name -> libs

remove the android-support-v4.jar.  If you do that, remove all imports startng with android.support.v4  and replace them with apropriate (non support) imports.

Comment: I have no libraries in my /libs folder. And I've removed the support library from the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code to app gradle file to avoid using support v4 lib

```
android {
configurations.all {   //this piece is important to avoid duplicates
        exclude group: 'com.android.support',
                module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Comment: is it just removing the duplicacy issue between dependencies. or it does not even include the support-v4 so that other low end devices also cannot use support-v4. when we do this ? @vuhoanghiep1993