# Stop android studio using support library in every template

Tags: android, android-studio

I have android studio 1.2.2 and it uses support libraries by default .
How to stop it i have tried the solution mentioned in 
[Stop Android Studio from using Support Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062094/stop-android-studio-from-using-support-library)

I made a project with no activity ,then i removed compile statement from gradle ,there is nothing in libs folder of the app module.

How to do it?

Comment: set your minimum supported sdk to 22 (or max value). it won't use support package there

Comment: but i want minimum sdk to be 14?

Comment: Edit the project after creating it to set `minSdkVersion` to 14 in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: well, create a completely new project with the minimum version of 22, then after Android Studio finish creating stuff for you, simply change that to 14, copy your code base, anything else into this new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean the project
change the theme of theme
rebuild
then add new activity it will not use by default